# nodejs, control over concurrent connections

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, concurrency

I am using nodejs async module for concurrent connectios, Now my backend server only can handle 1000 connections at a time, I am using async.mapLimit to limit the connections, each and every job of async.mapLimit does multiple connections, when I am sending the same request which does async.mapLimit from multiple browser at the same time, then I am getting EMFILE error from Server side

```
([Error: connect EMFILE] code: 'EMFILE', errno: 'EMFILE', syscall: 'connect'),
```

My code somewhat looks like this:

```
async.mapLimit(jobList, 200, jobCallback, function(error, data) {
});

function jobCallback(job, callback) {
    /* Make multiple connections to to backend server, this number is 
       dynamic, here also I use async.mapLimit */
}
```

Now I want to implement some wrapper function top of this mapLimit or anything, irrespective of number of parallel requests, I want to limit the concurrent connections, even irrespective of number of client calls also, it may be slower, but I do not bother.

How I can achieve this?

I am using restler library. I have tried to set

```
proto.globalAgent.maxSockets = 1000
```

to do concurrent 1000 connections at a time, but it seems it is not working.
Please advise.

-M-

Answer (score 0):

You will have to control for throttling yourself, as that async instruction won't know if you have calls from other users adding to the 1000 limit.

In REST services, a service would typically send an http 429 response when such a limit is triggered, allowing your app to identify a bottleneck scenario and trigger a throttling mechanism.

A common way to do that is via exponential backoff
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/backoff

Answer (score 0):

I use the following line of code to manage the limit globally:

```
require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 1000;
```

Thanks